# How to view expansion result after first step

Tags: makefile, preprocessor, gnu

with gnu make I can have commands and variables which are, afaik, **expanded** in a first step (kind of a preprocessor), and are actually **executed** in the second step.

So when I write:

```
$(OBJECTSFULL) :
    @echo ' '
    @echo '*** Compiling:   $(basename $(notdir $@)).cpp'

    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(LIBCCFLAGS) -I$(MAIN_INCLUDES) $(CXXFLAGS) \
    -MMD -MP -MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT"$(@:%.o=%.d)" \
    -o"$@" -c $(filter %/$(basename $(notdir $@)).cpp, $(SOURCES))  2>&1           
    @echo '*** Compiler finished'
```

, and my variable `$(OBJECTSFULL)` contains this: `src/foo.o src/bar.o src/baz.o`,

I expect that the "preprocessor" would create something like this prior to actually *build* the targets:

```
src/foo.o :
    @echo ' '
    @echo '*** Compiling:   foo.cpp'

    g++ -c     ......


src/bar.o :
    @echo ' '
    @echo '*** Compiling:   bar.cpp'

    g++ -c     ......


src/baz.o :
    @echo ' '
    @echo '*** Compiling:   baz.cpp'

    g++ -c     ......
```

The question:

**Is there any way that I can print out these results after the first step?** It would help me heaps for debugging a quite tricky makefile functionality with several $()-calls...

------edit------

To make it more precise: I generate makefile code dynamically. Imagine I have some "devices", I define them in a list:

```
devices := Car Bike Plane Ship
```

Then I define a template:

```
define make-device-lib
  LIBBASENAME$(1)   := device$(1)
  LIBNAME$(1)       := lib$$(LIBBASENAME$(1))
  LIBSONAME$(1)     := $$(LIBNAME$(1)).so
  LIBSOX$(1)        := $$(LIBSONAME$(1)).1
  LIBSOXX$(1)       := $$(LIBSONAME$(1)).1.1
  LIBSOXXFULL$(1)   := $$(SHAREDLIBDIR)/$$(LIBSOXX$(1))
  DEVICELIBS        += $$(LIBSOXXFULL$(1))

  OBJECTS$(1)       := $$(call objects_from_dirs, $$(SOURCEDIRS_$(1)))
  OBJECTSCOMMON     := $$(filter-out $$(OBJECTS$(1)), $$(OBJECTSCOMMON))

  $$(LIBSOXXFULL$(1)) : $$(OBJECTS$(1))
    @echo ' '
    @echo '*** Linking:   $$(LIBSONAME$(1))'
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(LIBLNFLAGS) -Wl,-soname,$$(LIBSONAME$(1)) -L$(SHAREDLIBDIR) $$^ -o $$@
    -@ln -f -s $$(LIBSOXX$(1)) $$(SHAREDLIBDIR)/$$(LIBSOX$(1))
    -@ln -f -s $$(LIBSOX$(1))  $$(SHAREDLIBDIR)/$$(LIBSONAME$(1))
endef
```

Now the code is actually generated for each "device", calling "make-device-lib":

```
$(foreach device,$(devices),$(eval $(call make-device-lib,$(device))))
```

Every $(1) in the template is replaced by each device name.
For example: `$$(LIBSOXXFULL$(1))` will eventually be expanded to `/usr/lib/libdeviceCar.so.1.1` in the first block, and `/usr/lib/libdeviceBike.so.1.1` in the second etc. `$OBJECTSCar` contains the automatically collected objects the target depends on ("objects_from_dirs" is another Macro which does so).

So when the line

```
$$(LIBSOXXFULL$(1)) : $$(OBJECTS$(1))
```

expands, make behaves as if I had written by hand:

```
/usr/lib/libdeviceCar.so.1.1 : Logging.o Printer.o Engine.o Seats.o
```

What i would like to see is this "virtual" makefile, so as if I had written everything by hand.

Comment: Have you tried `make -p` ?

Comment: Thanks for the good hint! not exactly what I expected, but at least it resolves all the variables and shows their content. I will try to get used to it.

Comment: Not all variables are expanded at first pass. Recursively expanded variables are not expanded until used. That said I've also often wanted to see the makefile that the first parsing pass is seeing.

Comment: @minastaros I faced the same problem when working with complicated makefiles. Did you find a solution? It would very useful?

Comment: @jmlemetayer Have you looked at `make -p` when you have `.SUFFIXES:` to disable implicit rules? It muddies it all up with a bunch of implicit garbage that was supposed to be turned off. It is full of misleading nonsense.

Answer (score 2):

Make always prints the command after it expands it and before it sends it to the shell, unless you prefix the line with `@`.  The output you see is *exactly* what make sends to the shell, which it sounds like is what you're looking for.

Can you explain what information you're missing?

If the problem is that you want to see the content hidden by the `@` you will need to either use the `--trace` flag (note this was introduced in GNU make 4.0), or remove the `@` (often people use a variable containing `@` that they can reset) or run with `-n`, but this can change the behavior of make as well.

*ETA:*

There is nothing other than `make -p` which will print the entire makefile, and that does not show the makefile in order as it was written originally; it just dumps make's internal database in whatever order it's stored.

For `eval` functions in particular, you can see exactly what make is parsing if you replace the `eval` call with an `info` call; so for example:

```
$(foreach device,$(devices),$(eval $(call make-device-lib,$(device))))
```

would be replaced by:

```
$(foreach device,$(devices),$(info $(call make-device-lib,$(device))))
```

Of course you can do both, and you can put the `info` version into some kind of conditional so it's only run if you specify a variable or something:

```
$(foreach device,$(devices),$(eval $(call make-device-lib,$(device))))
ifneq ($(VERBOSE),)
    $(foreach device,$(devices),$(info $(call make-device-lib,$(device))))
endif
```

However, to use this you'll obviously have to modify your makefile to support it; it's not built into make.

Comment: Hi MacScientist, I do not mean the output of each @-line. It is much more complex: code generating with templates, also with loops controlled by lists. See my edit above.

Comment: `make -p` prints database of all variables, but in case of complicated makefiles it is still complicated to expand macro/function invocation which generates rules on the fly.

Comment: Especially in case of Linux Kernel Makefile `make -p` is not that helpful in expanding such macro like this one: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v5.0/scripts/Makefile.lib#L181 . This macro generates prerequisites for a target. It tooks some time to understand what it is doing. Maybe you know some technique to simplify such macro expanding when debugging `Makefile`?

Comment: For things like this typically you write the same thing again but replace `eval` with `info`: `$(foreach m, $(notdir $1), $(info $(obj)/$m: ...` so it prints out what it would evaluate.  However I should point out that `-p` also prints all the rules as well so you can to look for the target you think should be created by this expansion and see how it's defined.